# Minecraft Scarpet - here or on Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, minecraft, game-modifications

It came to my attention that a Minecraft player, gnembon, has created a fully integratable, interpreted programming language for use in combination with Minecraft: [Scarpet](https://github.com/gnembon/scarpet) (link leads to GitHub repository. Introductory video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XO2kmbi_-Bk).). It's function is based on the Carpet mod (therefore Carpet Script = Scarpet).

It basically allows for an extension of classic commands to use various game mechanics alongside "classic programming features" like variables, loops, conditions, functions, etc.
It can be considered as a standalone language even though it's use outside of Minecraft is limited. On the other hand, it is focused to run and be ran by Minecraft in general and Minecraft commands in particular.

My suggestion would be, to consider it as a part of [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) or  [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods). One could as well argue that Stackoverflow provides a better focus on programming, even though less people would have the focus on Minecraft. In addition, Stackoverflow already has quite a few programming-related Minecraft questions.

In any case, I don't think this is a major problem (probably not more than a few questions in total), but I'd like to get this sorted out to avoid crossover content with SO. Will these programming-based questions be a good fit to this site? If yes, how to tag them?

Comment: I think it should be allowed as long as you don't ask questions along the lines of "my for loop is failing and I don't know why"

Comment: The discussion about this started here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XO2kmbi_-Bk&lc=UgzE-e37xf4CXgurP4x4AaABAg

Comment: @Robotnik thanks for the clarification edit, I didn't know these tags existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a good fit for the [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods) tag.

- The Minecraft questions on SO are more or less related to "real" Minecraft or plugin development (mostly Java)
- We already allow basic programming within the game's scope, such as command block chains and function files
- Carpet is a Minecraft mod, so the tag should be chosen accordingly

As you already mentioned the audience on SO is more focused on programming rather than Minecraft (although there are quite a few people doing both over there) and as it seems Scarpet is primarily for Minecraft, so it's more gaming related than actual programming. And only because Scarpet uses some programming techniques this doesn't mean it's actual programming, so this could be an issue on SO as well.

Comment: That's great, thank you. `We already allow basic programming within the game's scope, such as JSON scripts` is the main argument here. (I kinda dislike the `doesn't mean it's actual programming`, but it's true nevertheless). I'll leave the question open for a bit longer though.

Comment: On further thought, I'd put both the minecraft-mods and the minecraft-commands tags on such questions. Looking forward to see some of them :)

Comment: @RudolfJelin I didn't want to be rude with that part, sorry. And using the [tag:minecraft-commands] tag without actually using *Minecraft* commands is probably not a good idea. The commands used belong to the mod, not to the game.

Comment: 1. No, we do not allow plugin development questions here, they have to go on StackOverflow. 2. "JSON scripts" don't exist, JSON is data storage, not programming. 3. "doesn't mean it's actual programming" It is. Apart from that, when someone needs a [minecraft-scarpet] tag, just use [minecraft-commands] on a question and I'll see it and create the tag.

Comment: @FabianRöling 1. is not asked here. The plugin already exists and doesn't need to be developed. This Meta is about using it. 2. JSON extends JavaScript, so it's based off a scripting language and even object oriented (that's why it's called JavaScript Object Notation). 3. is not true from what I've seen. But even if it would it wouldn't change much. As FoxMcCloud already said, pure programming questions would not be allowed anyway. And 4. it still doesn't fit in [tag:minecraft-commands]. Only because it's using the Minecraft command line it does not necessarily use Minecraft commands.

Comment: 1. Sorry, I misread it. The answer said "on SO". 4. Ok. Is it possible to create a tag and follow it without having a question with that tag?

Comment: @FabianRöling that bullet point was meant to be a reason against posting it on SO, because it is not about development :) And you could create a tag using an existing question, if there is already one asking about Scarpet. If not it's probably best to just wait it out and create it when the first question pops up. I'm not sure how we deal with empty tags.

Comment: Empty tags are automatically deleted as far as I know. So I guess I'll just have to hope that someone uses it together with the [tag:minecraft] tag, so that I'm notified.

Comment: You can't script just with JSON.  The "Object Notation" part of the name is really important: it's notation used to describe JS objects.  In the context of Minecraft, JSON is basically useless without associated commands.  It is much better to describe the general case (command block chains and function files) than the specific case (the JSON within them).

Comment: Still, the question is, what place does it have, not if it is a programming language. AFAIK, `minecraft-commands` is fine as long as the question questions the mod in reference to / about the usage of commands. Otherwise, just `minecraft` and `minecraft-mods`. Another borderline topic is the more technical-issues side of things. How far do we go? It's not a typical mod, so I think some more flexibility could be possible. Any thoughts?

Comment: If it's using vanilla commands [tag:minecraft-commands] is fine. If not, [tag:minecraft-mods] is more appropriate. You can't tag a question with something it's not actually using. Commands in Scarpet are not Minecraft commands. And we don't allow tech support questions for modded Minecraft, so questions about technical issues with Scarpet would still be off-topic.